# Custom Json Deserializer for a generic class type

Tags: json, generics, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

Consider a json of type "Clothing":

```
{
  "id":"123",
  "version":2,
  "apparel":{
    "category":[
      {
        "id":"a1",
        "style":"top",
        "comments":[
         { 
          "header":{
            "type":"apparel.detail.Summary",
            "major_version":1,
            "minor_version":0
          },
          "summary": "notes"
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  "accessories":[
    {
      "header":{
        "type":"accessories.detail.Handbag",
        "major_version":1,
        "minor_version":0
      },
      "details":{
        "brand":"Gucci",
        "sno.":"G12"
      },
      "color":"Red",
    },
    {
      "header":{
        "type":"accessories.detail.Hat",
        "major_version":1,
        "minor_version":0
      },
      "details":{
        "brand":"Adidas",
        "sno.":"A12"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

"Clothing" is not accessible to me and I cannot add any field level or class level json annotations.
There is a property "header" in json that helps me to determine the type of class I want to convert that entity into. I will remove the header from my json once the class type is determined (since header is not defined in my target class type because of which deserialization will fail)

I need to write a custom deserializer that returns a generic class type object. It will check if there is header, fetch target class name, remove header and deserialize it to the fetched target class and return.

This is the code that I have written, but it does not work and I am not even sure if it is possible to have a custom deserializer injected in SimpleModule with a generic return type.

```
@Singleton
@Provides
private Transformer provideTransformer(final HeaderDeserializer headerDeserializer) {
    final SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
    simpleModule.addDeserializer(Object.class, headerDeserializer);
    mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
}


@Singleton
@Provides
private HeaderDeserializer provideHeaderDeserializer(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new HeaderDeserializer(objectMapper);
}

@Singleton
@Provides
private ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            // Tell object mapper how to handle joda-time.
            .registerModule(new JodaModule())
            // include non-null values only
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
            // ensures that timezone is preserved
    .disable(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE);
    return mapper;
}
```

My HeaderDeserializer looks something like this:

```
public class HeaderDeserializer<T> extends StdDeserializer<T> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final ObjectMapper mapper;

public HeaderDeserializer(final ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this(null, mapper);
}

public HeaderDeserializer(final Class<?> vc, final ObjectMapper mapper) {
    super(vc);
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

@Override
public T deserialize(final JsonParser jp, final DeserializationContext ctx) {
    Object value = null;
    try {
        JsonNode node = this.mapper.readTree(jp);
        JsonNode header = node.get("header");
        if (node.has("header")) {
            String targetClass = header.get("type").textValue();
            removeHeaderFromJsonDoc(node);
            value = this.mapper.readValue(jp, Class.forName(targetClass));
        }
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    } catch (final ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // do somehting
    }
    return (T) value;
}

private void removeHeaderFromJsonDoc(final JsonNode document) {
    final Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> itr = document.fields();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        final Entry<String, JsonNode> childNodeEntry = itr.next();
        if (childNodeEntry.getKey().equals("header")) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And my main deserializer which will use the custom deserializer defined above looks like:

```
public final Clothing deserialize(
        final String stringValue,
        final Class<? extends Clothing> clazz) {
    try {
        return this.objectMapper.readValue(stringValue, clazz);
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Comment: what "does not work" ? do you get an exception? wrong object type?

Comment: `HeaderDeserializer` is defined with generics but instantiated as raw type and associated to `Object.class` , so why define it with generics ? make it return `Object`

Comment: deserialize method of HeaderDeserializer is not called while deserialization.
I tried with your suggestion as well, but it all doesn't enter deserialize method.

Answer (score 0):

`this.objectMapper.readValue(stringValue, clazz);`
 Class type of 'clazz' in this readValue method should match class type passed in simpleModule.addDeserializer.

---

It is not going inside your deserializer because you are adding deserializer to SimpleModule for 'Object' class and reading value for different class passed to 'Clothing deserialize',